# multiple virtual hosts on EC2 ubuntu - cannot access second host, always accesses default

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-10.10, virtual-hosts, apache2.2

first time poster, but please help. I have been searching and reconfiguring for 6 days now and have lost several clumps of hair..

PROBLEM:
I want 2+ virtual hosts on my ubuntu server (1 ip)
BUT - Only the first "alphabetically" listed sites-enabled shows.
000-default
www.domain1.com
www.domain2.com

Individually they all work (if i a2dissite for each leaving 1)

CONFIG:
UBUNTU 10.10 Server
EC2 instance (dont shoot me for this part - hoping this isnt the issue!)
APACHE 2.2.16
DNS my.domain.com
 - to my public ec2 dns (this works)

Virtual Hosts:

## default

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/home/www/"
        <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Satisfy all
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/www>
        Options Indexes Multiviews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        </Directory>
        LogLevel debug
        ErrorLog /home/www/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /home/www/logs/access.log "combined"
</VirtualHost>
```

Virtual Host 1 - domain1

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@domain1.com
        ServerName domain1.com
        ServerAlias domain1.com www.domain1.com
        # Indexes + Directory Root.
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        DocumentRoot "/home/www/www.domain1.com/"
        # Directory directive
        <Directory "/home/www/www.domain1.com">
                Options Indexes Multiviews FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride none
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        # CGI Directory
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/www/www.domain1.com/cgi-bin
        <Location /cgi-bin>
                Options +ExecCGI
        </Location>
        # Logfiles
        LogLevel debug
        ErrorLog "/home/www/www.domain1.com/logs/error.log"
        CustomLog "/home/www/www.domain1.com/logs/access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I also have the above for domain2 in another document root with a different domain name

sym links are in place:
my apache2ctl -St shows the following - 
VirtualHost configuration:

```
*:80       is a NameVirtualHost
         default server  (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:4)
         port 80 namevhost  (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:4)
         port 80 namevhost domain1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www.domain1.com:4)
         port 80 namevhost www.domain2.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www.domain2.com:4)
Syntax OK
```

My ports.conf:
    NameVirtualHost *:80
    Listen 80

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    NameVirtualHost *.443
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

No changes from default to my apache2.conf and httpd.conf is empty.

I have tried the following (and about a hundred others):

[URL="http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2008/01/09/setting-up-name-based-virtual-hosting/"][/URL]
[URL="http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/vhosts.html"]http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/vhosts.html[/URL]
[URL="http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1466665.html"]http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1466665.html[/URL]
[URL="http://flurdy.com/docs/ec2/basics/index.html"]http://flurdy.com/docs/ec2/basics/index.html[/URL]
[URL="http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3282118.htm"]http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3282118.htm[/URL]

it seems i have tried everything that everyone else is having issues with but nothing seems to fix mine.

Possibilities:
1) EC2 
2) Permissions on the files - I changed everything to the apache2 user "www-data" - no dice.
3) I am a dope...lets hope its that and one of you kind people point me to my issue. :)

Chat soon...ill be over here losing my hair.
Regards, Logansanoh

Comment: Looks like it might be DNS related.
Trying a fix now...lets see what happens when the caches clear themselves!

Comment: This question doesn't have anything to do with ec2, it's how you configure Apache.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. I'm wondering if the hostname is getting passed to apache... i.e., it can only distinguish between named virtual hosts if it receives the name. As far as I can tell, it's not getting it, so it picks the first one as the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS was the culprit.
Everything was being passed as expected in both EC2, Ubuntu and Apache. The problem was I was using URL redirect at the DNS. This is stoopid! It was so simple, I set up an ANAME instead using my public IP address for the alias (www.domain1.com) and the same for the (www.domain2.com) and it all worked perfectly.
Now if i could only get TOMCAT to behave with mod_proxy i will be 100% there!!

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately Slicehost is slated to go down, but it has some good documentation on how to implement virtual hosts.
 visit :  
http://articles.slicehost.com/2010/5/19/apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-part-1 
http://articles.slicehost.com/2010/5/19/apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-part-2

I have shifted away from slicehost but their documentation still comes very handy.

As a side note, You are probably not getting a lot of response here because this question is better suited for : 
 http://serverfault.com

Best of luck, let us know how what was going wrong, Cheers!

Comment: Right. For those interested, it turned out to be DNS.
I needed a A Name in my DNS (mydomain.com)
Thanks for those that helped me at #ubuntu and #apache